# scope.$eval doesn't work in angular.js directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to build a angular.js directive, which by clicking the `<span>`, it will turn out into a editable input. and the following code works well, except when the model is empty or model length has 0, make it show `<span> EMPTY </span>`.

```
  <span  ng-editable="updateAccountProfile({'location':profile.location})" ng-editable-model="profile.location"></span> 

app.directive('ngEditable', function() {
    return {
        template: '<span class="editable-wrapper">' + '<span data-ng-hide="edit" data-ng-click="edit=true;value=model;">{{model}}</span>' + '<input type="text" data-ng-model="value" data-ng-blur="edit = false; model = value" data-ng-show="edit" data-ng-enter="model=value;edit=false;"/>' + '</span>',
        scope: {
            model: '=ngEditableModel',
            update: '&ngEditable'
        },
        replace: true,
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) { 

           var value = scope.$eval(attrs.ngEditableModel);
           console.log('value ' , attrs.ngEditableModel , value);
           if (value == undefined || (value != undefined && value.length == 0)) {
             console.log('none');
             var placeHolder = $("<span>");
             placeHolder.html("None");
             placeHolder.addClass("label");
             $(element).attr("title", "Empty value. Click to edit.");
           }


            scope.focus = function() {
                element.find("input").focus();
            };
            scope.$watch('edit', function(isEditable) {
                if (isEditable === false) {
                    scope.update();
                } else {
                    // scope.focus();
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

the problem occurs at the this part of code that

```
    var value = scope.$eval(attrs.ngEditableModel);
    console.log('value ' , attrs.ngEditableModel , value);
```

attrs.ngEditableModel output the content 'profile.location', but then using  scope.$eval() only output ' undefined ', even model 'profile.location' is not null

Comment: please use code snippet so we could see the working version of your code.(go to edit mode and then you could use Ctrl + M)

Comment: why are you using `scope.$eval` on an attribute which already assigned its value to your scope's `model` variable?

Answer (score 6):

You have two ways to fix that.

1) You're calling $eval on the wrong scope. You have in `scope` in your link function your newly created isolated scope. `attrs.ngEditableModel` does contain a reference to the outer scope of your directive, which means you have to call $eval at scope.$parent.

```
scope.$parent.$eval(attrs.ngEditableModel)
```

or 2) a better way to handle it: You already have bound ngEditableModel via your scope definition of

```
scope: {
    model: '=ngEditableModel',
```

So, instead of using your own $eval call, you can just use `scope.model` which points to the value of `attrs.ngEditableModel`. This is already two-way-bound.

Comment: it is strange that when console.log(scope), I could see scope.model value in the console, but when console.log(scope.model), outputs undefined.